# CSS and HTML in ELEMENTOR for a 1 Box Header Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, elementor

i would like to have my header to be in a "box" when hovering over it. Like it's on this website: https://www.dasbootshaus.at/de/das-bootshaus.html when you hover over it it fades in the whole dropdown at once. I tried to do this in elementor as a custom html & css and my code looks like that:

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">ÜBER UNS</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">GALERIE</a>
    <a href="#">LAGE</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.full_center_dropdown nav ul {
min-width: 100% !important;
}
.full_center_dropdown nav ul a {
justify-content: center;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
   font-family: LATO;
   transition: ease-in-out 0.8s;
margin-left: 20px;
  
    
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background: white;
    transition: background ease-in-out 0.5s;
    color: black;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
    left:-999em;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    background-color:white;
    transition: background ease-in-out 0.5s;;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

i tried different things with opacity and ease-in-out transitions but the dropdown always has a little delay. I hope someone can help me somehow :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't see your submenu ?

I think you did'nt indicate the new position that your element should have when you hover the button :

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {left: 0;}
```

For the moment, your element stays here :

```
left:-999em;
```

Have a nice day,